# j2objc command not found

Tags: android, ios, terminal, j2objc

I am trying to convert an android studio project to an iOS app. I have downloaded j2objc and it is in my downloads folder and I have unzipped it. The next step here: http://j2objc.org/docs/Getting-Started.html says that I can just type in j2objc + filename and have it converted, but for me it says: -bash: j2objc: command not found. I have looked at various solutions but none have worked for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Your command path doesn't include a reference to the j2objc distribution you unzipped. Find the full path for that directory, then do an "ls <the-path-you-found>/bin", where you should see the j2objc commands (if not, fix that path and try again). You can update the path for your current terminal window by running:

$ export PATH=${PATH}:*the-path-you-found*/bin

[Here is a article describing this in more detail](http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/), as well as how to set the path in MacOS for all terminal windows.